# C - Write Variable Parameter List to File

Tags: c, printf, variadic-functions

I'm using `va_list, va_start, va_end` to play with printf-like functions.

```
void test(char* format, ...)
{
    va_list argp;
    va_start(argp, format);
    vprintf(format, argp);
    va_end(argp);
}
```

Now I wonder how can I write all those parameters to file like `fwrite()` -> `vfwrite()` or something. Is there a way without implementing my own fwrite function that can write variable number of parameters ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you want [`vfprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/vfprintf).

It's just like `vprintf()` but it accepts a `FILE *` as its first argument.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like [vfprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vfprintf/) ?